Using 一点 as a complement of quantity after verbs
In the sentence
她能看到一点儿嫦娥住的月宫。
what's the purpose of 一点 after the verb 看到?
Is it a complement of quantity just like the following examples?

你看一会儿书。You read the book for a little while.
等一个小时。 Wait for one hour.


Quote:- "Using 一点儿 as a complement quantity...."
In the context of the sentence in question, 她能看到一点儿嫦娥住的月宫, 一点儿 is not used as a complement of "quantity", but as an indication of "portion"
嫦娥 has only one Moon Palace, (as far as we know), thus an observer sees either "a small portion", "a large portion" or "the whole" of the Palace.
So, 看到一点儿 = "sees a small portion", (in the context of the sentence)
If one sees a Large portion of the Palace, then it would be 看到一大部分.
If it is a complement of quantity, i.e. 嫦娥 has more than one Moon Palace, then the sentence would be 她能看到其中之一嫦娥住的月宫


what's the purpose of 一点 after the verb 看到?

一点儿 tells us how much of the Moon Palace she can see.
她能看到嫦娥住的月宫。
she can see 嫦娥 live de palace
She can see the Moon Palace where 嫦娥 lives.
一点儿的月宫: a little (bit of) the palace
她能看到一点儿嫦娥住的月宫。
she can see a little (bit of) 嫦娥 live 的  palace
She can see a little of the palace where 嫦娥 lives.
She must have an extremely good telescope!

"She must have an extremely good telescope!" If the telescope is extremely good, then the sentence would be "她能看到一大部分嫦娥住的月宫" :)

It is a well known fact, at least well known to me,  that 嫦娥住的月宫 lies mostly obscured from sight by 月山。大部分是不能看的。

It depends. In different context there may be two different understandings.
One scenario, ’She’ is looking at moon palace, but there is something block her sight, she can just see a bit part of the palace. Here you can say “她能看到一点儿(a bit part of)嫦娥住的月宫”.
While try another scenario, ’She’ is looking from a far distance and nothing block her sight, yet it’s too far to see the palace clearly. Here you can also say “她能看到一点儿(a little bit) 嫦娥住的月宫”. And here “一点儿” is more like kind of the degree she can see clearly or not.
